# c++: call overloaded function for derived classes as arguments too (without explicit cast)

Tags: c++, casting, overloading

Imagine the following scenario:

```
    template<class T>
    void myFunction(T *)
    {
       //do nothing
    }

    void myFunction(myBase * _base)
    {
       //do something with _base
    }

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    myDerivedFromBase * ptr = new myDerivedFromBase;
    myFunction(ptr); //calls the templated version

    myFunction(static_cast<myBase*>(ptr)); //calls the correct version

    delete ptr;
}
```

basically I want to achieve that the templated function gets called for pointers, that are not derived from my base. If a ptr is derived from myBase I want that the second version of myFunction gets called without the explicit cast. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use type traits to prevent the template from binding:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<myBase, T>::value, void>::type myFunction(T*)
{
}
```

If you can't use C++0x, use Boost's type traits library instead.

Comment: this does not come at a runtime speed penalty since it happens at compile time right?

Comment: Yes, it's entirely compile time (it prevents the compiler from matching the template for classes derived from myBase). Nothing extra happens at run-time.

Comment: okay, I tried this using boost but I can't seem to get it to work. I get the following error: template<class T>
typename boost::enable_if<!boost::is_base_of<myBase, T>::value, bool>::type myFunc(T * _bla)
{
 cout<<"bla"<<endl;
}/error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class Cond, class T> struct boost::enable_if'

 error:   expected a type, got 'boost::is_base_of<Ac,T>::value'

Comment: You need to use `boost::enable_if_c` to for the direct equivalent of my original version. Alternatively, with boost you can also do this: `template<typename T> typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_base_of<myBase, T>, void>::type myFunction(T*)`. The difference is that `boost::enable_if` expects a type having a bool value member, rather than a bool directly like C++0x's `std::enable_if`. `boost::enable_if_c` is the one that takes a bool.

Comment: this is slightly off topic, but do you know a way how I can forward boost::enable_if_c to become std::enable_if? I am currently simply forwarding all c++0x features to the std namespace if the platform does not support c++0x mostly using the "using" keyword. Any idea how I can rename enable_if_c to enable_if in that process?

Comment: Maybe this will work: `namespace std { template<bool Test, typename T> class enable_if : public boost::enable_if_c<Test, T> { }; }`?

Answer (score -1):

If you can use a pointer to base (see below), you can use template specialization:
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
class myBase {};
class myDerivedFromBase: public myBase {};

template<class T>
void myFunction(T *)
{
   cout << "Most general function." << endl;
}

template<>
void myFunction(myBase * _base)
{
   cout << "Specialized for myBase." << endl;
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    myDerivedFromBase * ptr = new myDerivedFromBase;
    myFunction(ptr); 
    delete ptr;

    myBase* bptr = new myBase;
    myFunction(bptr);
    delete bptr;

    bptr = new myDerivedFromBase;
    myFunction(bptr);
    delete bptr;
}
```

Comment: That's just using an implicit cast rather than an explicit one.

Comment: OP is trying to include more cases than just exact matches.